# Can I state a offer I got from a really small company where I didn't go to, to my next employers?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer

I got a offer letter from a company that claimed itself to be a game development studio. They hired me on the basis of a test project they had asked me to make, to test my skills. After completing and submitting the project I got selected.

I was never interviewed at their place and only had talked with the Co-Founder on phone. When I arrived at their 'office' at the first day, I was shocked as it was a really small and filthy cabin with only the co-founder and one more person in it, no AC or ventilation or even clean toilets/washrooms to use.

I left within 2 hours and never heard from that co-founder again. But the offer letter they game me was legit, it was well-written and really gave me the impression that I will be working with a decent company.

Can I show this offer letter in any future interviews or say that I'm currently working at this company? 
What will be the downsides of doing so? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to say you "[are] currently working at [the] company" when you are not?

Comment: Where do you live that showing offer letters from other companies is customary?

Comment: @Blrfl don't know about OP, but its common in India for a recruiter to ask details of any offer letters of other companies that a candidate may be having

Comment: @mu無 Aha, and OP's profile shows India.  I wonder what purpose it serves.

Answer (score 9):

> Can I show this offer letter in any future interviews or say that I'm
>   currently working at this company?

Yes you can. I wouldn't.

> What will be the downsides of doing so?

If future interviewers know of this company, they will likely also know that it was a tiny, filthy company. They would likely wonder why you would accept an offer from such a company.

And if you lie and say that you are currently working at this company, they may find out the truth and wonder why they should hire a liar.

I never recommend lying.

Answer (score 0):

Don't lie....

And if they ask how long you worked there and you say 2 hours and the rest of the story comes out you will have made yourself look a bit silly.

Will they then decide not to employ you? If you did that to me I would be looking at the other candidates who would look **so** much more sincere at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself *why* you got hired. Is it because you're really good at your job, or is it because nobody wants to work there, and you might as well cite babysitter as previous work experience?

Not actually speaking with a person face-to-face is a red flag, and should be a lesson for the future.

If I were you, I'd forget that this company ever came into your life. Pretend it never happened.

And *never, ever* lie during an interview, unless you're really good at it and they'll never find out. Because if they do find out, they know that they can't trust you. And that'll be pretty much the end of your career within that company.